# Align widget to the top part of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to align my widget to the top of the screen.

What my code is doing right now is that it starts from the center which is this portion of the code:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: BouncingBall(),
        ));
  }
}
```

I assume `Body: Center()` is centering my widget, is there a something that would align the widget to the top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget with `Alignment.topCenter` for the `alignment`

```dart
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child: Widget(), // replace 'Widget' with your widget
)
```

in your example

```dart
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: BouncingBall(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` like so:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Route"),
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BouncingBall(),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```